# Close parent visualForce page using javascript in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to close the page when you click on the button.

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account"  sidebar="false">
 <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/20.0/integration.js"/>
<pre>
 <script type="text/javascript">

      function test1() {
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel?")){
            window.top.close();
        }
      }

  </script>
 </pre>
  <apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton value="Test1" onclick="test1()" >
    </apex:commandButton>
 </apex:page>
```

How to correctly write ??

Comment: Just FYI, you can only use Javascript to close a page that you opened with Javascript in most browsers.  If this is only a Javascript question though your question is likely of-topic.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found on MDN about [window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.close):

This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method. If the window was not opened by a script, the following error appears in the JavaScript Console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

Comment: Thank you of course. I want to learn how to close the window. If anyone knows please answer.